# three.js passing events through iframe (onMessage)

Tags: javascript, iframe

Hey I am fairly new to three.js and js in general,
So I know my code isn't perfect by any means but even getting here was good advancement for me.

Anyway, my three.js scene is placed in a a website using an iFrame.
I would then like to control the camera position from the site itself.
with buttons.

What I basically did is write a window.onmessage function
that when triggered from the site itself call the function in the three.js in the iFrame.

However no matter what I do or where I place the message nothing happens.
I also tried to add a button directly to the three.js scene file but that had no effect as well, so I know I a missing something that might not be related to the iFrame but I have no idea what.

These are my onmessage events inside the three.js init function

```
window.onmessage - function(evt) {
    if (evt.data === 'setCamera01') {
        cameraPos = 300;
    }
}

window.onmessage - function(evt) {
    if (evt.data === 'setCamera02') {
        cameraPos = 0;
    }
}

window.onmessage - function(evt) {
    if (evt.data === 'setCamera03') {
        cameraPos = -300;
    }
}
```

And this is the code I place in my site where the iFrame is (#html2 is the IFrame)

```
export function button03_click(event, $w) {
    $w("#html2").postMessage('setCamera03');
    console.log("cameraPos = -300");
}

export function button02_click(event, $w) {
    $w("#html2").postMessage('setCamera03');
    console.log("cameraPos = 0");
}

export function button01_click(event, $w) {
    $w("#html2").postMessage('setCamera03');
    console.log("cameraPos = 300");
}
```

Finally in the Render function i place this line

```
camera.position.y = cameraPos;
```

And here you can see the full three.js code
(note I removed the urls of the models and textures because of NDA so you will not see a thing) I appreciate any help, Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>

<title>WebGL iFrame Test</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>

<style>
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    ;
}
.preloader {
    position: fixed;
    width: 32px;
    left: calc(50vw - 16px);
    top: calc(50vh - 16px);
    height: 32px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.container {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1.0s ease-out 0.5s;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<script>

    /* Global vars
    ---------------------------------------------------
    */

    var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
    var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

    var camera, scene;
    var canvasRenderer, webglRenderer;
    var models_loaded = false;
    var textures_loaded = false;
    var container, mesh, geometry, loader, preloader;

    var cameraPos = 300;

    var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    var light;



    var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

    /* 
    ---------------------------------------------------
    */





    /* Global materials and lighting controls
    ---------------------------------------------------
    */

    //material
    var roughness = 0.83;
    var metal = 0.8;
    var diffuse = 0x675f00;

    //lights
    var environmentInt = 0.5;

    var ambiLightInt = 0.2;
    var dirLightInt = 1.2;
    var dirLightScalar = 1;
    var hemiLightInt = 1;

    /* 
    ---------------------------------------------------
    */





    /* Page Preloader
    ---------------------------------------------------
    */

    preloader = document.createElement('img');
    preloader.onload = function(){
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", onmousemove, false);
        init();
        animate();
    }
    preloader.src = "textures_512/preloader.gif";
    preloader.className = "preloader";
    document.body.appendChild(preloader);

    /* 
    ---------------------------------------------------
    */





    /* init start
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    function init() {


        /* 3D Json Loader
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */

        container = document.createElement('div');
        container.className = 'container';
        container.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.body.appendChild(container);

        var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();

        manager.onStart = function ( url, itemsLoaded, itemsTotal ) {
            console.log( 'Started loading file: ' + url + '.\nLoaded ' + itemsLoaded + ' of ' + itemsTotal + ' files.' );
        };

        function onComplete(){
            if(models_loaded && textures_loaded){
                document.body.removeChild(preloader);
                container.style.visibility = 'visible';
                container.style.opacity =1;
                SITE_BACKGROUNDcurrentVideovideo.play();
                console.log( 'Loading completed');
            }
        }

        manager.onLoad = function ( ) {
            models_loaded = true;
            onComplete();
        };

        manager.onProgress = function ( url, itemsLoaded, itemsTotal ) {
            //console.log( 'Loading file: ' + url + '.\nLoaded ' + itemsLoaded + ' of ' + itemsTotal + ' files.' );
        };


        manager.onError = function ( url ) {
            //console.log( 'There was an error loading ' + url );
        };


        loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(manager);

        /* 
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */




        /* Creating the camera
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(20, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 10, 1500);
        camera.position.z = 340;




        /* Passing event (in the init function ?) through the iFrame
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */

        window.onmessage - function(evt) {
            if (evt.data === 'setCamera01') {
                cameraPos = 300;
            }
        }

        window.onmessage - function(evt) {
            if (evt.data === 'setCamera02') {
                cameraPos = 0;
            }
        }

        window.onmessage - function(evt) {
            if (evt.data === 'setCamera03') {
                cameraPos = -300;
            }
        }




        /* Bulding the scene
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        //Lights
        scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, ambiLightInt));


        /* Main light
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */

        light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, dirLightInt);
        //light.position.set(100, -350, 0);
        light.position.multiplyScalar(dirLightScalar);

        //light.position.x = 100;
        light.position.y = 100;
        light.position.z = 100;


        //Shadow parameters 
        light.castShadow = true;
        light.shadowCameraVisible = true;
        //light.shadowBias = 0.001;

        light.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
        light.shadowMapHeight = 1024;

        //Shadow camera fov and position
        var d = 50;

        light.shadowCameraLeft = -d;
        light.shadowCameraRight = d;
        light.shadowCameraTop = d;
        light.shadowCameraBottom = -d;

        light.shadowcameranear = 0.1;
        light.shadowCameraFar = 2000;
        light.shadowcamerafov = 30;
        light.shadowDarkness = 0;

        scene.add(light);

        /* 
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */


        //Skylight
        var skylight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x080820, hemiLightInt );
        scene.add( skylight );






        /* Texture Loader
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */

        var tx_manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
        tx_manager.onStart = function ( url, itemsLoaded, itemsTotal ) {
            //console.log(itemsTotal);
            //console.log( 'Started loading file: ' + url + '.\nLoaded ' + itemsLoaded + ' of ' + itemsTotal + ' files.' );
        };
        var total_textures = 0
        tx_manager.itemEnd=function (url){
            total_textures++;
            if(total_textures == 20){
                textures_loaded = true;
                onComplete();
            }
            //console.log(++total_textures);
        }
        tx_manager.onLoad = function ( x) {
            console.log(textureLoader);
            //console.log( 'tx_manager complete!');

        };

        var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader(tx_manager);


        /*
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */






        /* Environment map images
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */

        var envUrls = [
        'textures/env/02/px.jpg',
        'textures/env/02/nx.jpg',
        'textures/env/02/py.jpg',
        'textures/env/02/ny.jpg',
        'textures/env/02/pz.jpg',
        'textures/env/02/nz.jpg'
        ],

        // wrap it up into the object that we need
        cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(envUrls);

        // set the format, likely RGB unless you've gone crazy
        cubemap.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

        /*
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */






        /* 3D Json files loading
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */

        // TRUNK 01
        loader.load( "models/trunk_01.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var trunk_color = 0x0061ff;
                        //var trunk_01_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/trunk_01_curvature.jpg" );
                        var trunk_01_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/trunk_01_normal.jpeg" );
                        var trunk_01_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/trunk_01_roughness.jpeg" );

                    trunk_01_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: trunk_01_roughness,
                            normalMap: trunk_01_normal, 
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );

                        var trunk_01 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        trunk_01.material = trunk_01_Material;
                        trunk_01.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        trunk_01.position.x = 0;
                        trunk_01.position.z = 0;
                        trunk_01.position.x = 0;
                        trunk_01.castShadow = true;
                        trunk_01.receiveShadow = true;
                        trunk_one = trunk_01;
                        scene.add( trunk_01 );
        } );

        // TRUNK 02
        loader.load( "models/trunk_02.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var trunk_02_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/trunk_02_curvature.jpg" );
                        var trunk_02_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/trunk_02_normal.jpeg" );
                        var trunk_02_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/trunk_02_roughness.jpg" );

                    trunk_02_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: trunk_02_roughness,
                            normalMap: trunk_02_normal, 
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );

                        var trunk_02 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        trunk_02.material = trunk_02_Material;
                        trunk_02.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        trunk_02.position.x = 0;
                        trunk_02.position.z = 0;
                        trunk_02.position.x = 0;
                        trunk_02.castShadow = true;
                        trunk_02.receiveShadow = true;
                        trunk_two = trunk_02;
                        scene.add( trunk_02 );
        } );

        // LEAFS
            loader.load( "models/leafs.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var leafs_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/leafs_curvature.jpg" );
                        var leafs_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/leafs_normal.jpeg" );
                        var leafs_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/leafs_roughness.jpeg" );

                    leafs_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: leafs_roughness,
                            normalMap: leafs_normal, 
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );

                        var leafs = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        leafs.material = leafs_Material;
                        leafs.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        leafs.position.x = 0;
                        leafs.position.z = 0;
                        leafs.position.x = 0;
                        leafs.castShadow = true;
                        leafs.receiveShadow = true;
                        all_leafs = leafs;
                        scene.add( leafs );
        } );

        // ROSES
        loader.load( "models/roses.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var roses_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/roses_curvature.jpg" );
                        var roses_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/roses_normal.jpeg" );
                        var roses_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/roses_roughness.jpeg" );

                    roses_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: roses_roughness,
                            normalMap: roses_normal,
                            normalScale: new THREE.Vector2( 0.7, 0.7 ),
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );

                        var roses = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        roses.material = roses_Material;
                        roses.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        roses.position.x = 0;
                        roses.position.z = 0;
                        roses.position.x = 0;
                        roses.castShadow = true;
                        roses.receiveShadow = true;
                        all_roses = roses;
                        scene.add( roses );
        } );

        // TOPS
        loader.load( "models/tops.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var tops_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/tops_curvature.jpg" );
                        var tops_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/tops_normal.jpeg" );
                        var tops_roughness = textureLoader.load( "06/textures_512/tops_roughness.jpeg" );

                    tops_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: tops_roughness,
                            normalMap: tops_normal,
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );


                        var tops = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        tops.material = tops_Material;
                        tops.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        tops.position.x = 0;
                        tops.position.z = 0;
                        tops.position.x = 0;
                        tops.castShadow = true;
                        tops.receiveShadow = true;
                        all_tops = tops;
                        scene.add( tops );
        } );

        // STEMS
        loader.load( "models/stems.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var stems_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/stems_curvature.jpg" );
                        var stems_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/stems_normal.jpeg" );
                        var stems_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/stems_roughness.jpeg" );

                    stems_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: stems_roughness,
                            normalMap: stems_normal,
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );

                        var stems = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        stems.material = stems_Material;
                        stems.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        stems.position.x = 0;
                        stems.position.z = 0;
                        stems.position.x = 0;
                        stems.castShadow = true;
                        stems.receiveShadow = true;
                        all_stems = stems;
                        scene.add( stems );
        } );    

        // THORNES 01
        loader.load( "models/thornes_01.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var thornes_01_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/thornes_01_curvature.jpg" );
                        var thornes_01_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/thornes_01_normal.jpeg" );
                        var thornes_01_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/thornes_01_roughness.jpeg" );

                    thornes_01_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: thornes_01_roughness,
                            normalMap: thornes_01_normal,
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );

                        var thornes_01 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        thornes_01.material = thornes_01_Material;
                        thornes_01.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        thornes_01.position.x = 0;
                        thornes_01.position.z = 0;
                        thornes_01.position.x = 0;
                        thornes_01.castShadow = true;
                        thornes_01.receiveShadow = true;
                        thornes_one = thornes_01;
                        scene.add( thornes_01 );
        } );

        // THORNES 02
        loader.load( "models/thornes_02.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var thornes_02_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/thornes_02_curvature.jpg" );
                        var thornes_02_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/thornes_02_normal.jpeg" );
                        var thornes_02_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/thornes_02_roughness.jpeg" );

                    thornes_02_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: thornes_02_roughness,
                            normalMap: thornes_02_normal,
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );

                        var thornes_02 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        thornes_02.material = thornes_02_Material;
                        thornes_02.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        thornes_02.position.x = 0;
                        thornes_02.position.z = 0;
                        thornes_02.position.x = 0;
                        thornes_02.castShadow = true;
                        thornes_02.receiveShadow = true;
                        thornes_two = thornes_02;
                        scene.add( thornes_02 );
        } );

        // SNAKE BOSY
        loader.load( "models/snake_body.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var snake_body_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/snake_body_curvature.jpg" );
                        var snake_body_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/snake_body_normal.jpeg" );
                        var snake_body_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/snake_body_roughness.jpg" );

                    snake_body_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: snake_body_roughness,
                            normalMap: snake_body_normal,
                            normalScale: new THREE.Vector2( 1.5, 1.5 ),
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );

                        var snake_body = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        snake_body.material = snake_body_Material;
                        snake_body.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        snake_body.position.x = 0;
                        snake_body.position.z = 0;
                        snake_body.position.x = 0;
                        snake_body.castShadow = true;
                        snake_body.receiveShadow = true;
                        snake_b = snake_body;
                        scene.add( snake_body );
        } );

        // SNAKE HEAD
        loader.load( "models/snake_head.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var snake_head_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/snake_head_curvature.jpg" );
                        var snake_head_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/snake_head_normal.jpeg" );
                        var snake_head_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/snake_head_roughness.jpeg" );

                    snake_head_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: snake_head_roughness,
                            normalMap: snake_head_normal,
                            normalScale: new THREE.Vector2( 2, 2 ),
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );

                        var snake_head = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        snake_head.material = snake_head_Material;
                        snake_head.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        snake_head.position.x = 0;
                        snake_head.position.z = 0;
                        snake_head.position.x = 0;
                        snake_head.castShadow = true;
                        snake_head.receiveShadow = true;
                        snake_h = snake_head;
                        scene.add( snake_head );
        } );

        /* 3D Json files end
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */



        // RENDERER
        webglRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
        webglRenderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        webglRenderer.domElement.style.position = "relative";
        webglRenderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
        webglRenderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; // options are THREE.BasicShadowMap | THREE.PCFShadowMap | THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap

        container.appendChild(webglRenderer.domElement);
        window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}



/* init end
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/







/* Mouse mapping
---------------------------------------------------
*/

function onmousemove(event) {
    mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 6;
    mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 4;
}

/* 
---------------------------------------------------
*/





/* Window resize
---------------------------------------------------
*/

function onWindowResize() {
    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

    var f = (camera.aspect/1.583);
    if(f < 1){
        camera.position.z = 340 /(camera.aspect/1.583);
    }else{
        camera.position.z = 340;
    }

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    webglRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

/* 
---------------------------------------------------
*/








/* Animate
---------------------------------------------------
*/

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}

/* 
---------------------------------------------------
*/







/* Render
---------------------------------------------------
*/

function render() {

    // Camera
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    camera.position.x += ( - mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;   
    camera.position.y = cameraPos;
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    // Light Position
    light.position.x += ( - mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.03;
    light.lookAt( scene.position );

    // Render
    webglRenderer.render(scene, camera);
}

/* 
---------------------------------------------------
*/


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Did you check the javascript debugger? The code you posted doesn't seem valid so I'd assume it's printing lots of errors.

What is "window.onmessage **minus** function"?  Maybe you meant "window.onmessage **equals** function"???

Let's assume windows.onmessage = function is what you meant. You'd still have

```
window.onmessage = function ...
...
window.onmessage = function ...
...
window.onmessage = function ...
...
```

Setting `window.onmessage` 3 times is no different than setting anything else 3 times. Only the last time matters.

```
a = 1;
a = 2;
a = 3;
```

means `a = 3`.

If you want watch for multiple messages you need to assign just one function and then based on the data do something different

```
 window.onmessage = function(event) {
   switch (event.data.foo) {
     case 'hello':
       doSomethingWhenFooEqualsHello();
       break;
     case 'goodbye':
       doSomethingWhenFooEqualsGoodbay();
       break;
     case 'bingo'
       doSomethingWhenFooEqualsBingo();
       break;
   }
 }
```

Then when you call `postMessage` pass `{foo: 'hello'}` or `{foo: 'goodbye'}` etc. Of course it doesn't have to be `foo`. You make up the data and and decide how to figure out when one message means one thing and other equals another.

AFAIK iframes need to be on the same domain (could be wrong here but I'm not sure how you pass message or what iframe or HTTP headers you need to allow cross domain message passing)

Assuming they are on the same domain then I was able to pass a message with

#### index.html

```
<iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
<script>
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
setTimeout(() => {
  postMessage({foo: 123}, window.location.origin);
  iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({foo: 123}, window.location.origin);
}, 500);
</script>
```

#### iframe.html

```
<h1>iframe</h1>
<script>
window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
</script>
```

and finally three.js does not automagically render. If you want to render you either need a `requestAnimationFrame` render loop like you see in pretty much all of the examples on the three.js site OR, you need to call your own render function to re-render the scene anytime an event arrives that changes something.

Comment: Hey thank you. I got it working.

About the - / = a clear typo on my end. was just so tired and I totally missed it :/
Anyway It works, I didn't change yet to a switch statement but will be sure to do so.

About the requestAnimationFrame, if you look at the full code you will see it's there ;)

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey gman, not sure if I should continue here or not since now I have other new issues with the tween so I opened a new post about it.

I would appreciate it allot if you would have a moment to take a look at it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891758/three-js-camera-tween-with-switch-statement

Thank you