# three.js camera tween with switch statement

Tags: three.js, camera, tween.js

I am trying to tween a camera in three.js.
I have the following code in my init function.
A switch statement i am passing through an iFrame.

```
window.onmessage = function(evt) {
        switch (evt.data.cameraYpos) {

            case 'Ypos01':
                var from01 = {
                    y: camera.position.y
                };
                var to01 = {
                    y: yPos01
                };
                TWEEN.removeAll();
                var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(from01)
                    .to(to01, 600)
                    .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
                    .onUpdate(function() {
                        camera.position.set(this.y);
                        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
                    })
                    .onComplete(function() {
                        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
                    })
                    .start();
                break;

            case 'Ypos02':
                var from02 = {
                    y: camera.position.y
                };
                var to02 = {
                    y: yPos02
                };
                TWEEN.removeAll();
                var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(from02)
                    .to(to02, 600)
                    .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
                    .onUpdate(function() {
                        camera.position.set(this.y);
                        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
                    })
                    .onComplete(function() {
                        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
                    })
                    .start();
                break;

            case 'Ypos03':
                var from03 = {
                    y: camera.position.y
                };
                var to03 = {
                    y: yPos03
                };
                TWEEN.removeAll();
                var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(from03)
                    .to(to03, 600)
                    .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
                    .onUpdate(function() {
                        camera.position.set(this.y);
                        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
                    })
                    .onComplete(function() {
                        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
                    })
                    .start();
                break;
        }
    }
```

In my main website where the iFrame is, I have 3 buttons.
Once one of them is pressed I want the camera to animate to the new Y position.

```
export function button03_click(event, $w) {
    $w("#html2").postMessage({cameraYpos: 'Ypos03'});
    console.log("cameraPos = -300");
}

export function button02_click(event, $w) {
    $w("#html2").postMessage({cameraYpos: 'Ypos02'});
    console.log("cameraPos = 0");
}

export function button01_click(event, $w) {
    $w("#html2").postMessage({cameraYpos: 'Ypos01'});
    console.log("cameraPos = 300");
}
```

This is my animate function

```
function animate() {
    TWEEN.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}
```

and this is my render function

```
function render() {
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    camera.position.x += ( - mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
    webglRenderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

I manged to get it working with out a tween but now with the tween set
as soon as I press one of the buttons the model disappears from view.

I am sorry for not having a live version I am under strict NDA and switching the models just for this is allot of work. hope you understand.

Any help is most appreciated.
Thanks

You can see the full code here

```
<script>

    /* Global vars
    ---------------------------------------------------
    */

    var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
    var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

    var camera, scene;
    var canvasRenderer, webglRenderer;
    var models_loaded = false;
    var textures_loaded = false;
    var container, mesh, geometry, loader, preloader;

    var cameraPos

    var yPos01 = 300;
    var yPos02 = 0;
    var yPos03 = -300;

    var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    var light;



    var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

    /* 
    ---------------------------------------------------
    */





    /* Global materials and lighting controls
    ---------------------------------------------------
    */

    //material
    var roughness = 0.83;
    var metal = 0.8;
    var diffuse = 0x675f00;

    //lights
    var environmentInt = 0.5;

    var ambiLightInt = 0.2;
    var dirLightInt = 1.2;
    var dirLightScalar = 1;
    var hemiLightInt = 1;

    /* 
    ---------------------------------------------------
    */





    /* Page Preloader
    ---------------------------------------------------
    */

    preloader = document.createElement('img');
    preloader.onload = function(){
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", onmousemove, false);
        init();
        animate();
    }
    preloader.src = "https://assets.parastorage.com/marketingstudio/jessica_walsh/06/textures_512/preloader.gif";
    preloader.className = "preloader";
    document.body.appendChild(preloader);

    /* 
    ---------------------------------------------------
    */





    /* init start
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    function init() {


        /* 3D Json Loader
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */

        container = document.createElement('div');
        container.className = 'container';
        container.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.body.appendChild(container);

        var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();

        manager.onStart = function ( url, itemsLoaded, itemsTotal ) {
            console.log( 'Started loading file: ' + url + '.\nLoaded ' + itemsLoaded + ' of ' + itemsTotal + ' files.' );
        };

        function onComplete(){
            if(models_loaded && textures_loaded){
                document.body.removeChild(preloader);
                container.style.visibility = 'visible';
                container.style.opacity =1;
                SITE_BACKGROUNDcurrentVideovideo.play();
                console.log( 'Loading completed');
            }
        }

        manager.onLoad = function ( ) {
            models_loaded = true;
            onComplete();
        };

        manager.onProgress = function ( url, itemsLoaded, itemsTotal ) {
            //console.log( 'Loading file: ' + url + '.\nLoaded ' + itemsLoaded + ' of ' + itemsTotal + ' files.' );
        };


        manager.onError = function ( url ) {
            //console.log( 'There was an error loading ' + url );
        };


        loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(manager);

        /* 
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */




        /* Creating the camera
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(20, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 10, 1500);
        camera.position.z = 340;


        /* Passing event through the iframe
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */


        window.onmessage = function (evt) {
            switch (evt.data.cameraYpos) {

                case 'Ypos01':  
                var from01 = {y: camera.position.y};
                var to01 = {y: yPos01};
                TWEEN.removeAll();
                var tween01 = new TWEEN.Tween(from01)
                .to(to01, 600)
                .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
                .onUpdate(function () {
                    camera.position.set(this.y);
                    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
                })
                .onComplete(function () {
                    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
                })
                .start();   
                break;

                case 'Ypos02':  
                var from02 = {y: camera.position.y};
                var to02 = {y: yPos02};
                TWEEN.removeAll();
                var tween02 = new TWEEN.Tween(from02)
                .to(to02, 600)
                .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
                .onUpdate(function () {
                    camera.position.set(this.y);
                    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
                })
                .onComplete(function () {
                    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
                })
                .start();   
                break;

                case 'Ypos03':
                var from03 = {y: camera.position.y};
                var to03 = {y: yPos03};
                TWEEN.removeAll();
                var tween03 = new TWEEN.Tween(from03)
                .to(to03, 600)
                .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
                .onUpdate(function () {
                    camera.position.set(this.y);
                    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
                })
                .onComplete(function () {
                    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
                })
                .start();
                break;
            }
        };




        /* Bulding the scene
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        //Lights
        scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, ambiLightInt));


        /* Main light
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */

        light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, dirLightInt);
        //light.position.set(100, -350, 0);
        light.position.multiplyScalar(dirLightScalar);

        //light.position.x = 100;
        light.position.y = 100;
        light.position.z = 100;


        //Shadow parameters 
        light.castShadow = true;
        light.shadowCameraVisible = true;
        //light.shadowBias = 0.001;

        light.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
        light.shadowMapHeight = 1024;

        //Shadow camera fov and position
        var d = 50;

        light.shadowCameraLeft = -d;
        light.shadowCameraRight = d;
        light.shadowCameraTop = d;
        light.shadowCameraBottom = -d;

        light.shadowcameranear = 0.1;
        light.shadowCameraFar = 2000;
        light.shadowcamerafov = 30;
        light.shadowDarkness = 0;

        scene.add(light);

        /* 
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */


        //Skylight
        var skylight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x080820, hemiLightInt );
        scene.add( skylight );






        /* Texture Loader
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */

        var tx_manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
        tx_manager.onStart = function ( url, itemsLoaded, itemsTotal ) {
            //console.log(itemsTotal);
            //console.log( 'Started loading file: ' + url + '.\nLoaded ' + itemsLoaded + ' of ' + itemsTotal + ' files.' );
        };
        var total_textures = 0
        tx_manager.itemEnd=function (url){
            total_textures++;
            if(total_textures == 20){
                textures_loaded = true;
                onComplete();
            }
            //console.log(++total_textures);
        }
        tx_manager.onLoad = function ( x) {
            console.log(textureLoader);
            //console.log( 'tx_manager complete!');

        };

        var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader(tx_manager);


        /*
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */






        /* Environment map images
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */

        var envUrls = [
        'textures/env/02/px.jpg',
        'textures/env/02/nx.jpg',
        'textures/env/02/py.jpg',
        'textures/env/02/ny.jpg',
        'textures/env/02/pz.jpg',
        'textures/env/02/nz.jpg'
        ],

        // wrap it up into the object that we need
        cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(envUrls);

        // set the format, likely RGB unless you've gone crazy
        cubemap.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

        /*
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */






        /* 3D Json files loading
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */

        // TRUNK 01
        loader.load( "models/trunk_01.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var trunk_color = 0x0061ff;
                        //var trunk_01_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/trunk_01_curvature.jpg" );
                        var trunk_01_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/trunk_01_normal.jpeg" );
                        var trunk_01_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/trunk_01_roughness.jpeg" );

                    trunk_01_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: trunk_01_roughness,
                            normalMap: trunk_01_normal, 
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );

                        var trunk_01 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        trunk_01.material = trunk_01_Material;
                        trunk_01.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        trunk_01.position.x = 0;
                        trunk_01.position.z = 0;
                        trunk_01.position.x = 0;
                        trunk_01.castShadow = true;
                        trunk_01.receiveShadow = true;
                        trunk_one = trunk_01;
                        scene.add( trunk_01 );
                        //controls_01 = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(trunk_one, true);
        } );

        // TRUNK 02
        loader.load( "models/trunk_02.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var trunk_02_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/trunk_02_curvature.jpg" );
                        var trunk_02_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/trunk_02_normal.jpeg" );
                        var trunk_02_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/trunk_02_roughness.jpg" );

                    trunk_02_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: trunk_02_roughness,
                            normalMap: trunk_02_normal, 
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );

                        var trunk_02 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        trunk_02.material = trunk_02_Material;
                        trunk_02.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        trunk_02.position.x = 0;
                        trunk_02.position.z = 0;
                        trunk_02.position.x = 0;
                        trunk_02.castShadow = true;
                        trunk_02.receiveShadow = true;
                        trunk_two = trunk_02;
                        scene.add( trunk_02 );
                        //controls_02 = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(trunk_two, true);
        } );

        // LEAFS
            loader.load( "models/leafs.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var leafs_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/leafs_curvature.jpg" );
                        var leafs_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/leafs_normal.jpeg" );
                        var leafs_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/leafs_roughness.jpeg" );

                    leafs_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: leafs_roughness,
                            normalMap: leafs_normal, 
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );

                        var leafs = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        leafs.material = leafs_Material;
                        leafs.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        leafs.position.x = 0;
                        leafs.position.z = 0;
                        leafs.position.x = 0;
                        leafs.castShadow = true;
                        leafs.receiveShadow = true;
                        all_leafs = leafs;
                        scene.add( leafs );
                        //controls_03 = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(all_leafs, true);
        } );

        // ROSES
        loader.load( "models/roses.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var roses_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/roses_curvature.jpg" );
                        var roses_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/roses_normal.jpeg" );
                        var roses_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/roses_roughness.jpeg" );

                    roses_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: roses_roughness,
                            normalMap: roses_normal,
                            normalScale: new THREE.Vector2( 0.7, 0.7 ),
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );

                        var roses = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        roses.material = roses_Material;
                        roses.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        roses.position.x = 0;
                        roses.position.z = 0;
                        roses.position.x = 0;
                        roses.castShadow = true;
                        roses.receiveShadow = true;
                        all_roses = roses;
                        scene.add( roses );
                        //controls_04 = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(all_roses, true);
        } );

        // TOPS
        loader.load( "models/tops.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var tops_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/tops_curvature.jpg" );
                        var tops_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/tops_normal.jpeg" );
                        var tops_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/tops_roughness.jpeg" );

                    tops_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: tops_roughness,
                            normalMap: tops_normal,
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );


                        var tops = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        tops.material = tops_Material;
                        tops.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        tops.position.x = 0;
                        tops.position.z = 0;
                        tops.position.x = 0;
                        tops.castShadow = true;
                        tops.receiveShadow = true;
                        all_tops = tops;
                        scene.add( tops );
                        //controls_05 = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(all_tops, true);
        } );

        // STEMS
        loader.load( "jessica_walsh/06/models/stems.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var stems_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/stems_curvature.jpg" );
                        var stems_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/stems_normal.jpeg" );
                        var stems_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/stems_roughness.jpeg" );

                    stems_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: stems_roughness,
                            normalMap: stems_normal,
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );

                        var stems = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        stems.material = stems_Material;
                        stems.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        stems.position.x = 0;
                        stems.position.z = 0;
                        stems.position.x = 0;
                        stems.castShadow = true;
                        stems.receiveShadow = true;
                        all_stems = stems;
                        scene.add( stems );
                        //controls_06 = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(all_stems, true);
        } );    

        // THORNES 01
        loader.load( "models/thornes_01.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var thornes_01_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/thornes_01_curvature.jpg" );
                        var thornes_01_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/thornes_01_normal.jpeg" );
                        var thornes_01_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/thornes_01_roughness.jpeg" );

                    thornes_01_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: thornes_01_roughness,
                            normalMap: thornes_01_normal,
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );

                        var thornes_01 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        thornes_01.material = thornes_01_Material;
                        thornes_01.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        thornes_01.position.x = 0;
                        thornes_01.position.z = 0;
                        thornes_01.position.x = 0;
                        thornes_01.castShadow = true;
                        thornes_01.receiveShadow = true;
                        thornes_one = thornes_01;
                        scene.add( thornes_01 );
                        //controls_07 = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(thornes_one, true);
        } );

        // THORNES 02
        loader.load( "models/thornes_02.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var thornes_02_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/thornes_02_curvature.jpg" );
                        var thornes_02_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/thornes_02_normal.jpeg" );
                        var thornes_02_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/thornes_02_roughness.jpeg" );

                    thornes_02_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: thornes_02_roughness,
                            normalMap: thornes_02_normal,
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );

                        var thornes_02 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        thornes_02.material = thornes_02_Material;
                        thornes_02.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        thornes_02.position.x = 0;
                        thornes_02.position.z = 0;
                        thornes_02.position.x = 0;
                        thornes_02.castShadow = true;
                        thornes_02.receiveShadow = true;
                        thornes_two = thornes_02;
                        scene.add( thornes_02 );
                        //controls_08 = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(thornes_two, true);
        } );

        // SNAKE BOSY
        loader.load( "models/snake_body.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var snake_body_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/snake_body_curvature.jpg" );
                        var snake_body_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/snake_body_normal.jpeg" );
                        var snake_body_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/snake_body_roughness.jpg" );

                    snake_body_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: snake_body_roughness,
                            normalMap: snake_body_normal,
                            normalScale: new THREE.Vector2( 1.5, 1.5 ),
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );

                        var snake_body = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        snake_body.material = snake_body_Material;
                        snake_body.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        snake_body.position.x = 0;
                        snake_body.position.z = 0;
                        snake_body.position.x = 0;
                        snake_body.castShadow = true;
                        snake_body.receiveShadow = true;
                        snake_b = snake_body;
                        scene.add( snake_body );
                        //controls_09 = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(snake_b, true);
        } );

        // SNAKE HEAD
        loader.load( "models/snake_head.json", function( geometry, mat ) {

                        //var snake_head_color = textureLoader.load( "textures/snake_head_curvature.jpg" );
                        var snake_head_normal = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/snake_head_normal.jpeg" );
                        var snake_head_roughness = textureLoader.load( "textures_512/snake_head_roughness.jpeg" );

                    snake_head_Material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( {
                            roughnessMap: snake_head_roughness,
                            normalMap: snake_head_normal,
                            normalScale: new THREE.Vector2( 2, 2 ),
                            map: null,
                            color: diffuse,
                            metalness: metal,
                            roughness: roughness,
                            envMap: cubemap,
                            envMapIntensity: environmentInt
                        } );

                        var snake_head = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
                        snake_head.material = snake_head_Material;
                        snake_head.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                        snake_head.position.x = 0;
                        snake_head.position.z = 0;
                        snake_head.position.x = 0;
                        snake_head.castShadow = true;
                        snake_head.receiveShadow = true;
                        snake_h = snake_head;
                        scene.add( snake_head );
                        //controls_10 = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(snake_h, true);
        } );

        /* 3D Json files end
        ---------------------------------------------------
        */



        // RENDERER
        webglRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
        webglRenderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        webglRenderer.domElement.style.position = "relative";
        webglRenderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
        //webglRenderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
        webglRenderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; // options are THREE.BasicShadowMap | THREE.PCFShadowMap | THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap

        container.appendChild(webglRenderer.domElement);
        window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}



/* init end
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/







/* Mouse mapping
---------------------------------------------------
*/

function onmousemove(event) {
    //mouseX = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    //mouseY = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 6;
    mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 4;

}

/* 
---------------------------------------------------
*/





/* Window resize
---------------------------------------------------
*/

function onWindowResize() {
    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

    var f = (camera.aspect/1.583);
    if(f < 1){
        camera.position.z = 340 /(camera.aspect/1.583);
    }else{
        camera.position.z = 340;
    }

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    webglRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

/* 
---------------------------------------------------
*/








/* Animate
---------------------------------------------------
*/

function animate() {
    TWEEN.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}

/* 
---------------------------------------------------
*/







/* Render
---------------------------------------------------
*/

function render() {
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    camera.position.x += ( - mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    //Light Position
    light.position.x += ( - mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.03;
    light.lookAt( scene.position );

    webglRenderer.render(scene, camera);
}

/* 
---------------------------------------------------
*/



</script>
```

As seeinvisible said the tween is passing an object
with all 3 parameters and I tried to pass only the Y.

This is my updated tween

```
var from01 = {y: camera.position.y, z: camera.position.z};
var to01 = {y: yPos01, z: zPos01};
TWEEN.removeAll();
var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(from01)
.to(to01, 600)
.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut)
.onUpdate(function () {
    camera.position.set(camera.position.x, this.y, this.z);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
})
.onComplete(function () {
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
})
.start();
```

Comment: Unrelated tip: you can use `camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );` instead of `camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ) )`.

Comment: Thank you. updated my code. you can see the full code now in my post.
Hope it helps isolating the tween problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onUpdate function you have `camera.position.set(this.y)`.  However that seems to take 3 parameters x, y, z.  Try `camera.position.setY(this.y)` to only set the y value.

Comment: True. just figured it out today at work and logged in to share.
Thanks you :)